# How does one specify Channel ID in a Roku app?

Tags: roku, brightscript

I'm working on a completely new version of an existing Roku app, or I guess "Channel" in their parlance. Whether I'm trying to get a list of the products that I have created in the Roku Dashboard or just specifying what I want to buy by hardcoding the product identifier I'm never particularly surprised that it fails because how does Roku OS even know what app I am running as?

I mostly do iOS and Android and over there we have bundle identifiers or package names. On Roku there doesn't seem to be any channel id or anything. I can see one in the URL when I am editing it in the Roku Dashboard, but there doesn't even seem to be a value for the pkg:/manifest or field on ChannelStore to set.

In-Channel Product identifiers seem to be globally unique as I was first met with an error for the first product identifier I created. I thought maybe Channels keyed off their Channel name? Nope, I was able to name my Channel the exact same thing as another Channel.
I must have missed a very important piece of information somewhere when getting setup.

Can anyone out there give me a hint?

Update: I am now returning products from the ChannelStore which was an error in some code originally, but the question still stands, how does the Channel know what products are related to it? I will eventually need to point this all to the client's Channel.

Answer (score 0):

It appears these products are tied to your developer account which is what you are logged into on your Roku device. So all products from all channels on your account will appear.

Comment: For production/beta channels, products are tied with channel id and vanity code. Both are unique for every channel. Channel id and vanity code are assigned to each channel when channel is created. Channel id is non-editable where as vanity code is custom field and can be a custom string but should be unique across all roku channels. Every in-channel product is associated with one or more channels. In this way products are tied with channel via channel Id and vanity code.

Comment: This is not the that all the product available on roku account dashboard will be visible in any app. This is tied with right command used to fetch the in-channel products. One should use "getCatalog" command to get the products associated with only that particular channel.